# Security notion for asymmetric encryption when used in oblivious transfer

Tags: public-key, oblivious-transfer

[This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/993.pdf) paper suggests the following approach to oblivious transfer (OT), using asymmetric encryption:

1. Receiver generates keypair $(pk_b, sk)$, selects random $t$, and set $pk_{1 - b} = pk_b \oplus \mathsf{H}(t)$;
2. Receiver gives sender $pk_0, t$, and sender challenges receiver to confirm it knows how to decrypt one of $pk_0, pk_1$;
3. Sender encrypts its messages using $pk_0$ and $pk_1$.

On p.5 the paper correctly identifies that, for this scheme to be secure, the probability that the receiver can find $pk_0, \mathsf{H}(t)$ such that both $pk_0, pk_0 \oplus \mathsf{H}(t)$ can be decrypted must be negligible (Property 2.2).

In Section 5 the paper proves Property 2.2 using an argument of the following kind:

1. Assume the encryption is OW-CPA;
2. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an adversary, let $S_{\mathcal{A}}$ be the set of public keys which $\mathcal{A}$ may decrypt with non-negligible probability, i.e. if $\mathcal{A}$ were given this key during an OW-CPA game then $\mathcal{A}$ can win the game with non-negligible probability;
3. The size $|S_{\mathcal{A}}|$ must be negligible compared to $|\mathcal{U}|$, the space of all public keys, otherwise OW-CPA would be broken;
4. Let $D_{\mathcal{A}}$ be the set of all strings $s$ such that $s = pk_0 \oplus pk_1$ where $pk_0, pk_1 \in S_{\mathcal{A}}$. Then $|D_{\mathcal{A}}| = O(|S_{\mathcal{A}}|^2)$.
5. Since $|S_{\mathcal{A}}|$ is negligible, then $|D_{\mathcal{A}}|$ is negligible.

I find this argument flawed. If $|\mathcal{U}| = 2^\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the security parameter, while $|S_{\mathcal{A}}| = 2^{\lambda/2}$, then $|S_{\mathcal{A}}|$ is still negligible but one can no longer say $|S_{\mathcal{A}}|^2$ is also negligible. Hence, one needs to assume that $|S_{\mathcal{A}}|/2^{\lambda/2}$ is negligible, which is strictly stronger than OW-CPA.

Is there a known notion of security for asymmetric encryption that would imply this stronger bound on the number of keys the adversary may decrypt?